# How to produce ũ in my bibliography

Tags: biblatex, unicode, input-encodings

I am trying to produce Dũng as a name in my bib.
I do use `\~u` for this.

I am loading `inputenc` with the `utf8` option. the final result is  "Dng (2012)" in the text and "Dng, N. V. (2012)." in my Bib. So somehow the ũ is not encoded.

How can I tackle this?

Here is the code for the bib entry that I currently have:

```
@phdthesis{Dung:2012,
    Author = {D{\~u}ng, Ng{\^o} Vi},
    Date-Added = {2013-06-21T11:01:40GMT},
    Date-Modified = {2013-06-21 11:29:57 +0000},
    Title = {{An Institution-Based View of the Competitive Advantage of Firms in Emerging and Transition Economies}}
```

I do use biblatex to create my bibliography.

[image: Result in Bibliography]

This is the entry for the bibliography with my current settings:

This is the result when I cite the author.

[image: citeDung]

So somehow it does not seem that I get the correct ũ produced

This is a condensed verion of my LaTeX file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,oneside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backend=biber
            ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\bibliography{Bibliography_papers_test}  %

\begin{document} 

\section{One}

This is my test text \citeauthor{Dung:2012}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} \printbibliography%

\end{document}
```

Where

```
@phdthesis{Dung:2012,
    Author = {D{\~u}ng, Ng{\^o} Vi},
    Title = {{An Institution-Based View of the Competitive Advantage of Firms in Emerging and Transition Economies}},
        Year = {2012}
         }
```

Is my Bib file and

[image: Result]

Is the corresponding pdf

Comment: Check out this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet

Comment: @dustin This is not a question about symbols, it's a question about `bibtex`. You simply can't use UTF-8 encoded `.bib` files if you are using `bibtex`. You can switch to `biblatex` and `biber` which can handle this.  Otherwise you need to use `\~u`.

Comment: @wierts Can you construct a minimal document that shows what you did, and also show the `.bib` entry that you have?

Comment: You say "i do not want to use {~}u".  Are you open to other macro-oriented solutions (`\myfunction{u}`), or are you looking only for a font-related solution?

Comment: `bibtex8` can process utf8-encoded files.  Note that it is not really utf8 aware: e.g., `change.case$` won't work correctly, so you have to handle some entries specially.  But it may be rather easier than switching to Biblatex.

Comment: All Thanks for the answers upto know.

Here is the code for the bib entry that I have currently:

Comment: @wierts If I try a simple test document, I get the expected "Dũng". Can you add a minimal document? It's important to know how you load the bib file and how you produce the bibliography and citation.

Comment: I also see that the `oˆ` is displayed correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `biber` translates `\~u` to `ũ` and the standard set of Unicode characters provided by the `utf8` option doesn't know this character.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backend=biber
            ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0169}{\~u} % make the character known

\addbibresource{Bibliography_papers_test.bib} % better than \bibliography

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\section{One}


This is my test text \citeauthor{Dung:2012}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] % the bibliography goes to the TOC

\end{document}
```

If you load

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
```

then the Cyrillic T2A encoding is the default one, which is not wanted if the main language is English.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!

`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0169}{\~u} % make the character known`

This is what was missing, now the character does appear